# Mesh appears smooth, however it is not?

Tags: mesh, game-engine, modifiers, bezier-curves, edit-mode

[image: road in wireframe]
[image: road showing the bumpy problem]
The mesh itself is straight, but when viewed in texture mode it looks quite bumpy (renders this particular area in game as very bumpy and undrivable).
How do I fix this?
Note: array and curve modifiers used on mesh

Set 2:
[image]
[image]

Problem is, it renders as the bumpy road, not the smooth wireframe, and thus it is undriveable in-game.

-------------UPDATE-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
I have found somewhat a solution to this (in Nurbs curve data), it involves changing the twisting From Z-up to minimal or tangent, then playing with the resolution and turn on bounds-clamp (for mesh to hug the wireframe). It is not a perfect solution because now I need to re-do all control point tilts and locations for this 9km track. If anyone has a better solution, please share.
[image]

---

UPDATE 2: Even with twisting to minimal or even tangent, still getting weird artifacts in road mesh. Problem persists.
[image]
[image]

Comment: You need to redo the UV Unwrapping

Comment: UV unwrapping will only make textures look better right? the road will still drive bumpy, is the problem. Wireframe looks smooth, but it drives horribly

Comment: It isn't actually bumpy unless you added a modifier to it

Comment: modifiers have been used on both mesh and nurbs curve, how can I smooth it out?

Comment: Show us a screenshot of the modifiers please

Comment: you need to tear up that road, bring in a crew, and repave it. It does not cohere to *AASHTO* standards.

Answer (score 1):

The mesh is smooth, but very low poly with **long thin quads**. Such geometry can produce texturing artifacts - that's what you see.

You want to keep the topology in square quads.

To do so make just tileable chunk of the road (rectangle with nice topology), UV unwrap it and repeat it along a curve with Array and Curve modifiers, like so: [Create a road along large terrain](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7553/create-a-road-along-large-terrain)

Comment: will try this out when I get the chance. Work and studies might be a long while